# Can we make nepali character supported by codeigniter permitted_uri_chars

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make a page in nepali unicode. For that I need to get nepali characters of uri like 'http://localhost/vucl/page/2/some_nepali_characters'. The actual uri is shown in this [image: picture]. some stuffs like '%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B_%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE' is printed when i did

```
    print_r($this->uri->segment(3));exit;
```

the uri segment 3 actually is 'हाम्रो_बारेमा', a nepali characters. Now is there any possible way to make ci accept such character? I did this in config

```
    $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=+\p{L}';
```

But it didn't work. Any kind of help are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these line of  as specified:
in config.php

```
    $config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

in database.php

```
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

in php.ini set

```
    default_charset = "utf-8"
```